# Word Should used in strange context

Tags: meaning

I have a quote by Marquise de Laplace:

> It is remarkable that a science (Probability) which began with consideration of games of chance, should have become the most important object of human knowledge.

Why is *should* used in this quote? To me it reads as a mis-translation. Why is it not for example: *...became...* or *...has become...* in place of *...should have become...*. Is the meaning same? Is it some archaic way of saying the same thing?

Comment: It's ok.   it's + adjective + that   ............>>> subjunctive.   It's highly ironical that he should have said that.

Comment: It's relatively common in formal written English.

Comment: This would have been a translation from the French, *n’est-ce pas?*  Sometimes the structure of French forces the translator to choose between an awkward-sounding English expression that closely follows the original, or a more idiomatic expression that may not accurately convey the tone of the original writer.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your alternatives (*became* and *has become*) would also work and they wouldn't really change the meaning of the sentence.

*Should* has many uses as an auxiliary. This is not one of the most common, but it's not exactly rare:

> **used for describing a fact or event that someone has a particular feeling or opinion about**
>
> *It’s hardly surprising that people should be suspicious of politicians’ promises.*
> *How sad that she should have no one to comfort her.*
> *Claudia was shocked that anyone should believe such a scandalous story.*
> *It’s odd you should mention Ben – I was just thinking about him.*

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/should

It's interesting that that definition is in Macmillan's "American English" section. The *Cambridge Dictionary* marks this use as "mainly UK":

> mainly UK
>
> **used after "that" and adjectives or nouns that show an opinion or feeling:**
>
> *It's odd that she should think I would want to see her again.*
> *It's so unfair that she should have died so young.*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/should